# Python and powershell

Tags: python, powershell

When I write python in Powershell it doesn't return to anything like this **Python 2.7 (.......) Type "help
", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.**

Also, I am learning python 2 from Learn Python the Hard Way from Zed A Shaw. I am trying to do exactly as the teacher says in the book but I am unable to return the answer I am looking for.

I have attached the screenshot for the same, kindly help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in exercise 0, download and install python + update your path env variable etc.?

Comment: Yes, I did the same like copy and paste the [Environment]::SetEnvironment Variable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User") to configure the powershell.

Comment: Also when I write "python" in PowerShell to see the info., it takes me to the windows store to install python 3.8. Currently, I am learning python 2 as per the book.

Comment: Are you sure you installed python in `C:\python27`? Does `C:\python27\python.exe` actually exist?

Comment: Yes I have cross check this, by clicking right to python and check properties, also which folder it saves it is the same as C:\python 27\python.exe. I will try one more time, to go through the same process again may be I am missing something.